# Redis CROSSSLOT problem on Standalone Redis server

Tags: redis

I have a Standalone Redis node running in OpenShift/K8s as a Deployment. Regardless as to whether I add a ConfigMap with the `redis.conf` file or not, I keep on getting the wrethed CROSSSLOT error, when I try to connect a Spring Boot app via the spring.data.redis... properties:

`CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot.`

```
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:52) ~[spring-data-redis-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
...
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: CROSSSLOT Keys in request don't hash to the same slot
    at io.lettuce.core.internal.ExceptionFactory.createExecutionException(ExceptionFactory.java:147) ~[lettuce-core-6.3.1.RELEASE.jar:6.3.1.RELEASE/12e6995]
```

This is what the `redis.conf` file looks like:

```
requirepass $REDIS_AUTH

cluster-enabled no
tls-cluster no 
port 6379
appendonly yes
```

If I explicitly state that I do NOT have a cluster, why is this happening? Better still: how do I make this error go away?

My Deployment looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: redis-standalone
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: redis-standalone
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis-standalone
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis-standalone
    spec:
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redis-runtime
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: client
            - containerPort: 6380
              name: tls
          command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - redis-server /tmp/conf/redis.conf --requirepass $REDIS_AUTH
          env:
            - name: POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: REDIS_AUTH
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: redis-auth
                  key: passphrase
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 2Gi
            requests:
              cpu: '1'
              memory: 2Gi
          livenessProbe:
            tcpSocket:
              port: 6379
            initialDelaySeconds: 25
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 5
            successThreshold: 1
          readinessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/sh
                - -c
                - |
                  export REDISCLI_AUTH=$REDIS_AUTH
                  response=$(redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 ping)

                  if [ "$response" != "PONG" ] ; then
                    echo "Unable to ping the Redis master node"
                    exit 1
                  fi
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            periodSeconds: 3
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-standlone-config
              mountPath: /tmp/conf
              readOnly: false
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: { }
        - name: redis-standlone-config
          configMap:
            name: redis-standlone-config
            defaultMode: 0775
            items:
              - key: redis.conf
                path: redis.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. For future reference: the code snippets above are correct, apart from the fact that it misses as `persistentVolumeClaim`. So, if anyone needs an example of how to put together a Redis standalone node with K8s, this should go some way. The config could be tweaked further.

The problem was caused by the fact that I still had a rogue Redis node running as part of a StatefulSet within OCP. This interfered with my current Standalone Redis node, and caused the CROSSSLOT problem. I removed this node and the code is successfully saving the session id into the Redis server.